# Sharepoint list, add users (listed in a form field) to permission automatically without giving access to other list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, item-level-permissions

I have a list with permission setup as to be able to only see/modify list items created by a user. In the form we collect more names who would be responsible for this item (PM/BAs etc) and i would those additional users to be able to see/modify the list item along with one who created it.

is it possible to allow additional access without changing list setting (i know we could manage this via impersonate step in WF2010) but I only have SPD2013 and any other possible alternatives would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WF2010 has been deprecated in SPO, and WF2013 has also come to the countdown of the life cycle.

You could share the item directly to the users you want:
[image]